# What is the correct method of including php file

Tags: php

Following is my folder structure

```
test_folder
    pages_folder
        another.php
        header.php
    index.php
```

Now I want to include header.php file into index.php file as well as another.php file and both of these files resides in a different directory.

If my header.php file has an image element whose source is relative to the header.php file then index.php is not going to load the image element.

I am getting the following error

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).

So my question is how should I include header.php file into index.php and another.php so both of these files can load the image element.

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mcve], and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: What makes you think that the 404 error is in any way related to the question of including files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **relative path** or **absolute path**. Best is **absolute path** since can include folders and files wherever they are without having to guess the exact path...

simple **relative path**:

```
<?php
  include("test_folder/pages_folder/another.php");
  include("test_folder/pages_folder/header.php");
  include("test_folder/index.php");
?>
```

or better with **absolute path**:

```
<?php
  include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/test_folder/pages_folder/another.php");
  include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/test_folder/pages_folder/header.php");
  include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/test_folder/index.php");
?>
```

where [$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) is the **root** of your server... so you can begin from it to [include](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) your files.

Some **xampp** configurations add to the path the `"/index.php/"` folder which produces an error loading the relative elements... for example, if you have a style sheet in the root of your server and want to add it to your php file that you find also in the root you will notice that the css file will point to this structure: `server` / `index.php` / `style.css` and not to `server` / `style.css`. If this is your case you should set [AcceptPathInfo Off](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo) in your `VirtualHost` or `.htaccess`. This will produce a `404` error when encounter a `/index.php/` or you can put into your `.htaccess` this rule:

`.htaccess`

```
Options -Multiviews
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index\.php(/.*) $1
```

This rule has the benefit to rewrite on fly the urls removing the unwanted `/index.php/` from path.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

The correct way to include a file is... include!

Variations are include_once, require and require_once

**Make sure to ALWAYS use an ABSOLUTE path when including.**